# How can you debug a CORS request with cURL?

Tags: curl, cors

How can you debug [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) requests using [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)? So far I couldn't find a way to "simulate" the preflight request.

Answer (score 687, accepted):

Here's how you can debug CORS requests using curl.

**Sending a regular CORS request using cUrl:**

```
curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" --verbose \
  https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis?fields=
```

The `-H "Origin: http://example.com"` flag is the third party domain making the request. Substitute in whatever your domain is.

The `--verbose` flag prints out the entire response so you can see the request and response headers.

The URL I'm using above is a sample request to a Google API that supports CORS, but you can substitute in whatever URL you are testing.

The response should include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

**Sending a preflight request using cUrl:**

```
curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
  -X OPTIONS --verbose \
  https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis?fields=
```

This looks similar to the regular CORS request with a few additions:

The `-H` flags send additional preflight request headers to the server

The `-X OPTIONS` flag indicates that this is an HTTP OPTIONS request.

If the preflight request is successful, the response should include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and  `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers.  If the preflight request was not successful, these headers shouldn't appear, or the HTTP response won't be 200.

You can also specify additional headers, such as `User-Agent`, by using the `-H` flag.

Comment: that page does not seem to return any CORS headers, is that correct?

Comment: In order to view the actual headers, you need to add the `--verbose` option, as mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm, that may be a bug. Can you try the same request to the following url: http://server.cors-api.appspot.com/server?id=3349374&enable=true&status=200&credentials=false&methods=GET%2CPOST&headers=X-Requested-With

Comment: --verbose wasn't displaying headers for me either.   I replaced it with "--trace-ascii -"

Comment: or `--head`: `curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" --head https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis\?fields\=`

Comment: Use --include to see the headers.

Comment: In the case of S3, the according headers are only added if the proper method is given, you can do so by using `curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: http://example.com" -I https://s3.amazonaws.com/your-bucket/file`.

Answer (score 117):

Use:

```
curl \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
-H "Origin: http://localhost" \
--head \
http://www.example.com/
```

1. Replace http://www.example.com/ with the URL you want to test.
2. If the response includes `Access-Control-Allow-*` then your resource supports CORS.

**Rationale for the alternative answer**

I google this question every now and then and the accepted answer is never what I need. First, it prints the response body which is a lot of text. Adding `--head` outputs only headers. Second, when testing [S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) URLs we need to provide additional header `-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET"`.

Comment: if I curl without setting origin and I can get response and headers(including access-control-allow-origin header) back, does that mean I set up my CORS incorrectly? 

curl -X GET 'https://www.endpoint.com' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --head

Comment: This relies on `--head` making curl print out the headers, but it also makes curl make a `HEAD` request rather than a `GET`. Depending on what you're testing, you may want to make a `GET` request. You can do this by adding `--IXGET`.

Comment: Isn't this backwards? Shouldn't the origin be example.com instead?

Comment: If the request returns a 404 does it mean anything other than "you got the url wrong"?

Comment: @jcollum yes; you might have got the URL wrong, but it might also be that the URL is correct but the resource is not there (outdated?); or that is there but is not reachable, for some reason (bug in the routing? in the load-balancer rules? etc.). – By the way, issues with CORS would return a 403.

Comment: This is probably the best answer out there that solved my problem. Thanks @Vilius!

Comment: This can’t be the best answer because it’s wrong: a preflight request is done with `OPTIONS`, not `HEAD` or `GET`.

Answer (score 7):

The preflight request is done using the [`OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#preflighted_requests_in_cors) HTTP method.

Assuming you want to test CORS on a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request from *http://mysite.example.com* to *https://myapi.example.com/foo*, the command should be:

```
curl -XOPTIONS \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
  -H "Origin: http://mysite.example.com" \
  https://myapi.example.com/foo
```

The response is either `OK` or an error message like *Disallowed CORS origin*. You can still include the headers using `-i` if you’d like.

This is a lot simpler than some other responses that make either [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) or [HEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) requests and ask you to interpret the headers.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like just this works:

`curl -I http://example.com`

Look for **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`** in the returned headers.

Comment: Remember that `*` doesn't work if credentials such as a cookie need to be presented with the API request. In that case the FQDN is required in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response as well as `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.  Credentialed requests though weren't specified as a requirement by OP, so `*` works for any unauthenticated requests.

Answer (score 2):

The Bash script "corstest" below works for me. It is
based on [Jun711's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl#comment89608525_47609921).

**Usage**

corstest [-v] URL

**Examples**

```
./corstest https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json
https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The positive result is displayed in green:

```
./corstest https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jsonrequest
https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jsonrequest does not support CORS
You might want to visit https://enable-cors.org/ to find out how to enable CORS
```

The negative result is displayed in red and blue.

The -v option will show the full curl headers.

**corstest**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2018-09-20
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/47609921/1497139

# ANSI colors
#http://www.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html
blue='\033[0;34m'
red='\033[0;31m'
green='\033[0;32m' # '\e[1;32m' is too bright for white background.
endColor='\033[0m'

#
# A colored message
#   parameters:
#     1: l_color - the color of the message
#     2: l_msg - the message to display
#
color_msg() {
  local l_color="$1"
  local l_msg="$2"
  echo -e "${l_color}$l_msg${endColor}"
}


#
# Show the usage
#
usage() {
  echo "usage: [-v] $0 url"
  echo "  -v |--verbose: show curl result"
  exit 1
}

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  usage
fi

# Commandline option
while [  "$1" != ""  ]
do
  url=$1
  shift

  # Optionally show usage
  case $url in
    -v|--verbose)
       verbose=true;
       ;;
  esac
done


if [ "$verbose" = "true" ]
then
  curl -s -X GET $url -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --head
fi
origin=$(curl -s -X GET $url -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --head | grep -i access-control)


if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  color_msg $green "$url $origin"
else
  color_msg $red "$url does not support CORS"
  color_msg $blue "you might want to visit https://enable-cors.org/ to find out how to enable CORS"
fi
```

Comment: adding the Origin header would make it better e g. *-H 'origin:https://mydomain.xyz'*

Comment: I downvoted because 1- 99% of this script is irrelevant to the answer; 2- the command used in the script is the same as the accepted answer written 6 years before; 3- that command is wrong: preflight requests use `OPTIONS`, not `GET` nor `HEAD`.