# How to setup Angular and OpenId behind load balancer

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, load-balancing, openid

I'm trying to use cross domain authentication in my Angular/.net Core 2.0 app using OpenId.

for this purpose I'm using angular-auth-oidc-client package. the authentication API is behind a load balancer and I'm currently getting an error in browser .

> Failed to load https://xyz//.well-known/openid-configuration: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5002' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

How to add equivalent of `ForwardedHeadersOptions` (.net core) in Angular 4?

Is there any other package for `Angular` which provides the option to set the ForwardedHeaders ?

Answer (score 0):

We have an [Angular 4](https://angular.io/) front end hosted on [AWS S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html), with an [AWS elastic load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) behind which we have multiple [EC2 servers](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) each running a [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) service behind an [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) proxy.

The REST requests from the front end reaches the server without [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues:

- without the AWS elastic load balancer and directly to the EC2 server

The REST requests breaks with the CORS errors from the front end and not reaches the server:

- with the AWS elastic load balancer and not directly to the EC2 server

Although we're not yet successful but [these are the stuff (as per @agentspacecake)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=619662) which we have tried so far:

1. Allowed CORS in the [S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html), example [config](https://gist.github.com/tommoor/4429838) - done
2. Allowed CORS in the back end using [CORS node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) - done
3. Allowed CORS in the [nginx proxy using the CORS headers](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) - done
4. Allow CORS on the load balancer's front - **not done**

Based on my studies so far:

- Per @Max@AWS, we [need to whitelist the "Origin" header](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=190886)
- Per @Brian@AWS, we'd [want to whitelist the "Origin" and any other headers you'd like to forward](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=156446)
- This was a [bug in the past](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101805) especially for chrome
- As per @Arun@AWS, the [requests needs to contain the headers which are expected to return](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103604)
- Not sure if the [browser caching could surface the CORS issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=112772)
- Per @hescar, we can also try [adding a 'Origin' header](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103604)
- Looks like, [we shall not use * wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18029490/2404470)
- The AWS staff says that [ELB doesn't support CORS yet](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=147318#527641)
- The [feature request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=508201&#508201) to ELB CORS support still looks open
- The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/cors-support.html) says that the JSON `Content-Type` is not allowed in simple/actual requests

> Requests only use the GET or POST HTTP methods. If the POST method is used, then Content-Type can only be one of the following: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.

Hope this helps to some extent.