# CURL doesn't send POSTFIELDS correctly to some servers

Tags: php, json, curl

I've tried searching, the other answers didn't help me.

I'm trying to send POST data via cURL, but it's only working on *some* servers. What gives?

I've tried:

```
if (!empty($data) && $usePost) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}
```

`$data` contains an array with the key of `products` and the value of a JSON string.

I also tried explicitly using the query:

```
if (!empty($data) && $usePost) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
}
```

But still, `$_POST` on the receiving server gives me `NULL`.

Any idea what to do?

Here's the whole method:

```
public static function execCommand($command, $ch,$data=array(),$cookie_file='genCookie.txt', $usePost = false) {
    $url = $command;
    if (!empty($data) && !$usePost)
        $url .= '?' . http_build_query($data);
    elseif (isset($data['sessionid'])) {
        $url .= '?sessionid=' . $data['sessionid'];
        unset($data['sessionid']);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    if (!empty($data) && $usePost) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

I tried echoing `$_REQUEST`, so it's not in `$_GET` by mistake. I also tried `file_get_contents('php://input')`, but still nothing.

Both the sending and receiving ends are on Apache servers.

Bigger thing is, it's working on *most* servers, but only *some* are ignoring it. Is there a safer, more cross platform way to do this?

Comment: _What_ servers? IIS? Apache HTTPD?

Comment: Can you paste your full curl settings block?

Comment: Updated. Both sides are Apache, and the code is in the original question

Comment: when it happens? When you change the client (the server where there is this code) or when you change the endpoint? (the server that receive the post)?

Comment: Enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to see the request and response headers

Comment: Can you share any information on the number of servers you are attempting and if there is anything different about the servers that are failing?

Comment: Set the appropriate headers. Maybe it is a CORS request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl

Comment: Please add how you are reciving/evaluating the $_POST on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem, was the SSL on the receiving server. The request was being made to `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`, and instead of giving an error or redirection, it simply dropped the POST on the way (maybe it redirected to HTTPS but failed to pass the POST along with it?)

Answer (score 4):

I find it difficult to believe that Curl is not sending "post" fields to some servers (the code you shared looks OK). I would rather assume that there is something wrong with how you handle POST on those servers or you do something wrong elsewhere.

You can troubleshoot with tcpdump

```
$ sudo tcpdump -nl -w - -s0 -A -c 500 tcp port 80 | strings
```

Now if you run an example code like:

```
<?php

class Curl {

    protected static function getCurlHandler( $url, $data = false, $headers = false ) {
        $ch =  curl_init(); 

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );

        if( $headers ) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        }

        if( $data ) {
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $data ) );
        }

        return $ch;
    }

    protected static function exec( $ch ) {
        $output = curl_exec( $ch );

        // handle errors

        curl_close( $ch );
        return $output;
    }

    public static function get( $url, $headers = array() ) {
        $ch = self::getCurlHandler( $url, false, $headers );

        return self::exec( $ch );
    }

    public static function post( $url, $data = array(), $headers = array() ) {
        $ch = self::getCurlHandler( $url, $data, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

        return self::exec( $ch );
    }

    public static function put( $url, $data = array(), $headers = array() ) {
        $ch = self::getCurlHandler( $url, $data, $headers );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

        return self::exec( $ch );
    }

    public static function delete( $url, $data = array(), $headers = array() ) {
        $ch = self::getCurlHandler( $url, $data, $headers );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");

        return self::exec( $ch );
    }

}


Curl::post( "http://www.google.com", array('q' => 'hello world'));
```

You should find something like this in the TCPDUMP output

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
q=hello+world
```

The last line is the most interesting bit which clearly shows that CURL sent a POST request with the required data.

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative is to use `wget` which essentially downloads a file from a location. It is probably going to be a bit slower as you need to then open the file you download and delete the space. I am not confident it scales well and it's not going to be good for `POST` requests. cURL works using port 80, which is the basic browser port. That means that if you can access it via a browser, cURL will work.

Through the limited information you gave I can provide some troubleshooting tips.

In this instance I am calling your PHP server that initiates the request the **client** and the server you are sending information to the **server**.

The first thing you should do is make sure that this is working on your server. Check your source code.

Step 1. Try to submit a form and make sure `$_POST` returns information. If it does, you can move on. If it doesn't you have a very, very strange bug. I would be interested to know if you are using different OSes on these different servers.

Step 2. Check your server `sessionid`. Make sure your client is expecting them to come via `GET`. I know this may seem obvious, but many times the obvious is the source of failure. What does your server do if your `sessionid` fails? Make sure your processing script returns something like:

```
if(session_is_registered($_GET['sessionid']) {
    echo "This is a registered session.";
    $_POST['debugSessionExists'] = true;
} else {
    echo "This sesion does not exist.";
    $_POST['debugSessionExists'] = false;
}
```

You should be able to spit out return data on your client too thanks to the `echo`.

Step 3. Do the same thing for all of your `$_POST` variables and echo a return.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    echo "{$key} exists and has the value of $value.<BR />";
}
echo "Done checking $_POSTs.";
```

The reason I advise this is because I am not sure how you have been checking your `$_POST` values to date and it doesn't hurt to see if your cURL response is getting information you are not seeing. This means that the way you are storing your $_POST values is just not transferring on some of your servers and that is your point of failure.

I will be interested to find out what is returned via these results.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, you might need to do tcpdump to see exactly how the data is going to the server.

You might be running into the 'Expect' header with curl which can be disabled:

http://the-stickman.com/web-development/php-and-curl-disabling-100-continue-header/

By disabling the Expect header, there is a perf. advantage of avoiding additional round-trips between the client and the server albeit at the cost of bypassing additional checks on the server side (e.g. enforcing maximum POST body size etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging with http://req.uest.info/

Also have you checked the logs of your originating server?

Answer (score 0):

> Bigger thing is, it's working on most servers, but only some are ignoring it.

The POST is sent ok, but the server differ. For starters, compare the PHP versions.

For example; [since PHP 4.2.0 `register_globals` is off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals), which could give similar `NULL` results if the receiving end reuses variable names like `$foo` VS `$_POST['foo']`.

> Is there a safer, more cross platform way to do this?

No, a POST is a good way to send data. But keep in mind that data is sent plaintext over the wire unless you use encryption or https.