# CORS response headers not working in Spray when requested from browser

Tags: jquery, scala, cors, spray, http-options-method

I was attempting to implement CORS support on a Spray server (version 1.1-20131011 where cors headers are already supported).

Currently, the server code looks like this:

```
trait DefaultCORSDirectives { this: Directives =>
  def defaultCORSHeaders = respondWithHeaders(
      `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`(AllOrigins),
      `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`(HttpMethods.GET, HttpMethods.POST, HttpMethods.OPTIONS, HttpMethods.DELETE,
      HttpMethods.CONNECT, HttpMethods.DELETE, HttpMethods.HEAD, HttpMethods.PATCH, HttpMethods.PUT, HttpMethods.TRACE),
      `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`("Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host," +
    " Referer, User-Agent, Overwrite, Destination, Depth, X-Token, X-File-Size, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control"),
      `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`(true),
      `Access-Control-Max-Age`(3600)
    )
}
```

and is used like this

```
  defaultCORSHeaders {
      options {
        complete {
          StatusCodes.OK
        }
      } ~
      post {
        path("path") {
          //response
      }
   }
```

The responses for both POST and OPTIONS methods are as expected when using curl. However from browser, I get Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin (Chrome) or Error 415 Unsupported Media Type (Firefox) and it seems the POST request is not even sent at all.

The requesting jQuery code is simply as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.post(url,
            {
               'params': "params",
            },
            function (data) {
                //handle response
            }
    );
});
```

I have read the CORS spec and all the resources I could find, tried any possible combination of the Access-Control-Allow- headers (with and without Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, different content of Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to * or the single Origin etc.). I have also tried running the script from disk (Origin null), webserver (Origin localhost:8888) and remote server (Origin standard url), because some browsers apparently block requests with local origin, but always the same negative result.

Any help how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't use a directive, but I tried rawheader and it works.

code is as following:

```
 path("ping"){
   get{
     respondWithMediaType(`application/json`){
       respondWithHeader(RawHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")){
         complete{
           jsonPrefix + """{"result": "PONG"}"""
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have authorization in your API you must include the Authorization header in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

The only way to test cors from cUrl is if you use the Origin header: [curl cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl)

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a new directive:

```
trait CORSSupport extends Directives {
   private val CORSHeaders = List(
     `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS),
     `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`("Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, User-Agent"),
     `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`(true)
   )

   def respondWithCORS(origin: String)(routes: => Route) = {
     val originHeader = `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`(SomeOrigins(Seq(HttpOrigin(origin))))
     respondWithHeaders(originHeader :: CORSHeaders) {
       routes ~ options { complete(StatusCodes.OK) }
     }
   }
 }
```

Making use of the new directive:

```
trait Api extends Directives with RouteConcatenation with CORSSupport with ConfigHolder{
    this: CoreActors with Core => 

    val routes =
      respondWithCORS(config.getString("origin.domain")) {

        pathPrefix("api") { 
          new DemoRoute().route
        } 
      }

    val rootService = system.actorOf(ApiService.props(config.getString("hostname"), config.getInt("port"), routes))
  }
```

https://github.com/wesovilabs/spray-cors-demo/blob/master/README.md