# Why do wildcard CORS permissions not work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, cors

I am using `loadGeoJson` to try and load data across domains. I am aware that I need to implement CORS to provide the necessary permission. The response header needs to include the following declaration:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I have modified the apache2.conf file in /etc/apache2 and added the following:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

When I load my page containing the cross domain script in Firefox, everything works fine and I can see that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin has been set:

[image: Firefox]

The problem arises when I load the same page in Chrome where I continue to receive the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
> Origin 'http://results.ptax.ca' is therefore not allowed access.

How can the same page work perfectly in Firefox, but throw an error in Chrome?  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what the request and response headers look like in Chrome (similar to what you did in JavaScript)? Also, can you recreate the CORS request using curl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl

Comment: Hi @monsur, I am using CodeIgniter, and for some reason I configured a Base Site URL, even though doing so is optional.  Once I removed this particular configuration setting, I stopped getting the error for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: That is good to know. I'm curious, what does the code to set the Base Site URL look like?

Comment: The setting in CodeIgniter is in /application/config/config.php and this is it:  ` $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mydomain.ca/'`

Answer (score -2):

Chrome sometimes rejects wildcard CORS (`*`). This happens for example if you are using the `withCredentials` option.

Set the actual domain (including protocol and [if neccessary] port like `https://example.com:8008`) in your CORS config.