# Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Notes Agent

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest, xpages

Here's my doubt: I have an Xpage that makes a cross-domain GET request... the URL is a notes agent in other domain that returns a XML code. I need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow it, and I found how to set it in the domino server configuration... can I set it dinamically too in this notes agent that generates the XML? How should I do it? after the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>` I can insert it as a custom header? does it work? Thanks in advance for help on this issue

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099835/how-do-i-setup-cors-on-lotus-domino ?

Comment: Yes Dmytro I've seen that one... but I found a solution... The agent prints the XML response line by line... and it starts printing: `Print "Content-type: text/xml"` . I added a line below that: `Print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"` ... and voilá! it is returning the XML for me now! Thanks!

Comment: Please, write it as an answer to your own question.