# Enable/configure CORS in Domino 9.0.1 FP 10

Tags: rest, cors, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ibm-domino

Is there any way to Enable/Configure CORS in Domino 9.0.1? I am trying to make some cross origin REST api calls to my domino server, but its getting failed.

I have tried so many things as of now(getting information from many places), but nothing seems to be working.

Does Domino9 supports CORS at all? and if not, then is there any way to make cross origin REST api calls to that? Any information on this is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For releases prior to Domino 10.0.1 FP2, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099835/how-do-i-setup-cors-on-lotus-domino). But for future reference, Domino includes a built-in [CORS filter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_10.0.1/admin/conf_cors.html) starting with 10.0.1 FP2. That's a more secure option if you can use it.

Answer (score -1):

check this https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21962324 or you could put a reverse proxy in front of your domino to add theses headers