# Convert cURL string to Resteasy

Tags: java, http, post, curl, resteasy

I have trouble converting an example cURL string (that works) to a meaningful resteasy expression. The cURL is:

```
curl -X POST -u admin:admin --data-binary "@tempfile.xml" http://localhost:8810/rest/configurations
```

I have:

```
public void sendPost(ConfigurationDTO config) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
    // client target is:  http://localhost:8810/rest
    ResteasyWebTarget target = getTarget();
    target.path("configurations");
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ConfigurationDTO.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    // this here produces exactly what I need
    marshaller.marshal(config, new File("test.xml"));

    MultipartFormDataOutput dataOutput = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
    dataOutput.addFormData("file", new FileInputStream(new File("test.xml")), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = new GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput>(dataOutput) {};


    Response response = target.request().post( Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));
    response.close();
}

protected ResteasyWebTarget getTarget() {
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri(restUrl).build());
    client.register(new AddAuthHeadersRequestFilter(user, pass));
    return target;
}
```

Throws HTTP.500, I don't have access to the server to see what happened.

Comment: First I'm missing the user-password information in your code.

Comment: It is done in `getTarget()`, also GET requests do work, so no problem there.

Comment: Should I understand it that you can call GET requests via your RESTEasy client and it works?

Comment: Yes. No problems with GET, works as expected. The client is composed in the same method (added to original post). Only POST-s return HTTP.500

Comment: Is your RESTEasy client running on a diffent port than your REST service? If so, have you configured CORS header only for GET requests?

Comment: I have not (manually) set the port for the client. I simply would like to post request to an external service using the RESTEasy client the same way as the docs suggests (the cURL expression)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to debug CORS in cURL (see [How can you debug a CORS request with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl)). In your case, it is a command:

```
curl --verbose -u admin:admin \
  -H "Origin: http://localhost:1234" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
  -X OPTIONS \
  http://localhost:8810/rest/configurations
```

Please, replace `localhost:1234` with a context path where your RESTEasy client is running on.

If the request is not successful, it means a problem with CORS configuration. The request is successful if the response contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: The cURL-call is working, problem is the RESTeasy code. Also here can be no CORS problems as neither curl nor the RESTeasy client have a Same-Origin-Policy.

Answer (score 1):

cURL is sending the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when using the `--data-binary` argument. You are using `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE (multipart/form-data)` so I'd expect that your server does not accept the latter. RESTeasy then would throw `javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Cannot consume content type`.

I don't understand why you are marshalling your entity to a file and passing this file to the RESTeasy client. Using e.g. a `StringWriter` your code could look like this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(config, sw);
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(sw.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
```

Is the server part also written by you? If you are only sending xml files `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not seem to be the best matching ContentType.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Writing to a file was for debug purposes mostly. Server is not written by me, it is like a blackbox, I am just testing it as we consume it. I will try your suggestions on Monday.