# How to solve "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: go

I'm implementing REST API's in Go and for that I want to allow cross origin requests to be served.

What I am currently doing:

Go server code:

```
//handleCrossO ... This function will handle CROS
func handleCrossO(w *http.ResponseWriter) {
(*w).Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
(*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
(*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, 
     OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
(*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, 
     Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, 
     Authorization, Auth")
}

//Response ... This function will create response
func Response(w http.ResponseWriter, message string, statusCode int) 
{
handleCrossO(&w)
w.WriteHeader(statusCode)
w.Write([]byte("{\"message\":\"" + message + "\"}"))
}
```

I am getting the following error on browser console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ip:8080/config' from origin 'http://ip:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have also tried the following code to check OPTIONS method:

```
// CheckAuthorization function check if the User is autrhorized to make calls or not
// if ssid is mising then give unauthorized error otherwise call next
func CheckAuthorization(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        //handle preflight in here
        response.Response(w, "success", 200)
    }else {
            store := session.SessionStore()
        session, _ := store.Get(r, utils.SessionName)
        ssid := r.Header.Get("Auth")
        if _, ok := session.Values[ssid]; ok {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        } else {
        var getTokenRes = GetTokenRes{}
        sendResponse(w, getTokenRes, 1, "Invalid 
                     SSID", 400)
        }
    }

}
}
```

But it is not working.

I have also tried allow OPTIONS method:

```
router.HandleFunc("/network", authmiddleware.CheckAuthorization(createConfiguration)).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")
```

Comment: I had issues with CORS and i implemented my own library. But it did not work. Chrome kept blocking mine. I used https://github.com/rs/cors and it it did the job for me. Also I was creating cookies from server side. Unless you have https or same origins server side cookies will not be accepted by chrome. However you can create cookie from the client.

Comment: my code for CORS https://github.com/26prajval98/GetMaid-Server/blob/master/src/GetMaid/handlers/middlewares/enableCORS.go

Comment: You seem to be using gorilla/mux, if that's the case I'd recommend you use their [CORS](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#CORS) middleware with the [AllowedOrigins option](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#AllowedOrigins) passing in `"*"` and if that doesn't work, then passing in a list of the allowed origins, eg `"http://ip:4200", "http://ip:8080", ...`.

Comment: ... and also take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985920/making-golang-gorilla-cors-handler-work), you may find the answers useful.

Comment: @mkopriva I have already tried that way but still not my problem is not resolved.

Comment: You're passing a pointer to an interface `w *http.ResponseWriter` which is almost never the behavior you want, and is why your code is littered with `(*w).MethodCall` junk. Consider changing it to accept a parameter `w http.ResponseWriter` like every other function that takes a `ResponseWriter`.

Answer (score 2):

[Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) should return success and headers. Try to use like following

```
func setupResponse(w *http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    setupResponse(&w, req)
    if (*req).Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }

    // process the request...
}
```

Also you can use https://github.com/rs/cors

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write([]byte("{\"hello\": \"world\"}"))
    })

    // cors.Default() setup the middleware with default options being
    // all origins accepted with simple methods (GET, POST). See
    // documentation below for more options.
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(mux)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
}
```