# How to handle Preflight requests for DELETE calls with Gorilla?

Tags: go, cors, gorilla, http-status-code-405, mux

I wrote a simple API with the [Gorilla Web Toolkit](https://github.com/gorilla), handling the CORS answers through its [handlers](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers):

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/api/note", readHandler).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/api/note", writeHandler).Methods("POST")
r.HandleFunc("/api/note", deleteHandler).Methods("DELETE")
r.HandleFunc("/api/note", optionsHandler).Methods("OPTIONS")
```

optionsHandler is

```
func optionsHandler(_ http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    return
}
```

My rationale behind this is that a Preflight call will use `OPTIONS` but the only thing it is interested in are the relevant CORS headers.

`GET` and `POST` work fine, a JavaScript [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) call goes through with the right headers.

`DELETE` however fails on the Preflight call: Chrome DevTools states that a `DELETE + Preflight` call fails with `CORS error`, the next line is the Preflight `OPTIONS` call that fails with a 405 ("Method Not Allowed")

**Why do I get this error when the method is handled? And how to fix it?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985920/making-golang-gorilla-cors-handler-work - Are you sure that preflight is sent for `GET` and `POST`?

Comment: @LarsChristianJensen: yes it is (I checked the headers, and the calls go through from JS). I found the issue and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating the `CORS()` call:

```
methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"OPTIONS", "DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH"})
origins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
headers := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Content-Type"})
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.42:80", handlers.CORS(methods, origins, headers)(r)))
```

I think (but I am not sure) that what actually fixed the call is the `headers` entry.