# CORS preflight mysteriously failing with gorilla/handlers

Tags: go, cors, http-headers, wildcard, gorilla

I am publishing a Golang API for my application through Heroku. Not able to get my webapp (Flutter/Dart stack) to actually get a successful response from my api. However I *am* able to get a successful response using curl commands from local. I've read through several posts about altering the Go mux server and adding the correct headers but this has not worked for me. I even see these headers returned back during my curl requests. Could really use some help as this is slowing me down.

essentially this is my main class which creates the server

```
import (
    "api/preventative_care"
    "api/user"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Llongfile)
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    // Where ORIGIN_ALLOWED is like `scheme://dns[:port]`, or `*` (insecure)

    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"*"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})

    router.HandleFunc("/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Up and running!")
    })
    router.HandleFunc("/api/login", user.LoginHandler).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/recommendations", preventative_care.RecommendationHandler).Methods("GET")

    var port = os.Getenv("PORT")
    log.Printf("Starting application on port %s\n", port)

    //log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), router))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":" + os.Getenv("PORT"), handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(router)))

}
```

And the dart code which calls this API looks like this:

```
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "username": username,
      "password": password
    };

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: headers);
```

I'm hosting both the webapp and the API in 2 separate Heroku Dynos. When I hit the API from my local using curl I see below:

```
$ > curl -iXGET https://my-app-api.herokuapp.com/api/login -H "username:hello" -H "password:pizza"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 18 Nov 2021 23:39:56 GMT
Content-Length: 160
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

I thought I was supposed to see see the Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` added there but it's not yet I still get 200 success back. However when I try to use my Webapp to hit the API from a login screen using Google Chrome I see this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-app-api.herokuapp.com/api/login' from origin 'https://my-app-staging.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

No idea - it's like the header is being removed by Chrome or something maybe?

EDIT: I've also tried sending a preflight request using CURL and I am seeing the correct headers - however it's still showing me 4XX error.

```
$ > curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: https://my-app-staging.herokuapp.com" --head https://my-app-api.herokuapp.com/api/login

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Fri, 19 Nov 2021 00:51:52 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

So now I'm REALLY not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

[gorilla/handlers](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers) doesn't (yet?) support the wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. You must specify all the allowed headers explicitly. In your case, instead of

```golang
handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"*"})
```

you should have

```golang
handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"content-type", "username", "password"})
```

### More details

The [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) added support (in the case of non-credentialed requests) for the wildcard in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header [back in 2016](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/commit/cdbb13c08650b10c9ebfc54d046bec0639e7ba7c). Most modern browsers now [support this feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#browser_compatibility).

However, [gorilla/handlers](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers) doesn't seem to have caught up with the spec yet. If you inspect the source code for [the `handlers.AllowedHeaders` function](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/3e030244b4ba0480763356fc8ca0ade6222e2da0/cors.go#L193) and for [the `*cors.ServeHTTP` method](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/3e030244b4ba0480763356fc8ca0ade6222e2da0/cors.go#L50), you'll see that there's no special handling of the `"*"` value: it's treated literally. As a result, the CORS middleware [detects a mismatch](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/3e030244b4ba0480763356fc8ca0ade6222e2da0/cors.go#L85) between the request headers supplied by your preflight request (`content-type`, `username`, and `password`) and your allowed headers (`*`, taken literally) and [responds with a `403`](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/3e030244b4ba0480763356fc8ca0ade6222e2da0/cors.go#L86) without even setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, thereby causing the access-control check to fail.

Comment: This did fix it for me - it's just a really confusing error from the browser because even though I've specified the Allowed-Origins * - it complains to me that Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is missing when in fact it should mention something that the headers I tried to pass are not accepted by the server!

Comment: @alex In this case, `gorilla/handlers`'s implementation arguably is to blame for your confusion. The browser was telling you the truth: the response to the preflight request did not contain any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, because `gorilla/handlers` only [sets that header further down the `*cors.ServeHTTP` method](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/3e030244b4ba0480763356fc8ca0ade6222e2da0/cors.go#L132), once and only if all the request headers have been successfully checked against your allowed headers.

Comment: Really great analysis there - didn't even consider that could be the case. Thanks