# .NET Core UseCors() does not add headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, cross-domain-policy

This would be a duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work), but the method there also isn't working for me. I'm hoping I'm just missing something.

I am trying to get a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in my response from my .NET Core Web API, which I am accessing via AJAX.

I have tried several things. All, unless noted otherwise, have been in the `Startup.cs` file.

**Method 1**

As per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add database
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")));

    // Add the ability to use the API with JSON
    services.AddCors();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext>().EnsureSeedData();
        }
    }

    app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44306").AllowAnyMethod());

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
        Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Audience"],
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowWebApp",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyOrigin()));
                          //.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44306")));

    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ...

    app.UseCors("AllowWebApp");

    // ...
}
```

I've also tried adding `[EnableCors("AllowWebApp")]` on both the Controller and Method.

From Postman, I get:

> content-encoding → gzip
>   content-type → text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   date → Wed, 25 Jan 2017 04:51:48 GMT
>   server →Kestrel
>   status → 200
>   vary → Accept-Encoding
>   x-powered-by → ASP.NET
>   x-sourcefiles → =?UTF-8?B?[REDACTED]

I've also tried it in Chrome, and gotten similar headers.

If it matters, the method I'm trying to access has an `Authorize` attribute on it. But that part should be working fine (I'm at least getting a good response)

So, am I missing something very obvious, or did this get broken? I'm currently running version 1.1.0.

---

**Edit adding JS and Controller Stub**

```
function getContactPreviews(resultsCallback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            resultsCallback(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response));
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://localhost:44357/api/User/ContactsPreview", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("AuthorizationToken"));
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Controller Stub

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet(nameof(ContactsPreview))]
    [EnableCors("AllowWebApp")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> ContactsPreview()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you hitting the server with Postman? The header will only be returned for an OPTIONS request

Comment: @Rob. That's what I was missing. Less so on the Postman side (I had tried it in Chrome as well, and that was using the correct method), and more so on the controller side. I had `[HttpGet]` instead of `[HttpOptions]`. I had a feeling it'd be something dumb like that.

Comment: @Rob, however, Chrome is still failing. It's getting a 204 error. Postman works perfectly. Both are using the same Bearer token. Cache is disabled in Chrome.

Comment: That.. doesn't seem correct to me. You shouldn't have to mark your controller method as `HttpOptions`. Your code in Method 1 looks correct (just checked against my local project, which works). I feel like chrome was failing because it cached the pre-flight OPTIONS request, and postman was failing because you weren't sending an OPTIONS request.

Comment: Even though the cache is disabled, can you inspect your network log and check that the OPTIONS preflight was actually sent?

Comment: Also note that 204 is not an error. 204 is a success code, it means the server had no data.

Comment: @Rob Yes, I know on the 204 part. Although there should be data. The API returns some JSON. Anyways, it's using the options method. Here's what Chrome is showing: http://imgur.com/a/M2FJx

Comment: Okay, so 204 is expected in this case as this is the preflight request before sending the *actual* request. What methods does your controller action accept? Have you explicitly marked it as HttpPost if it's a post method for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133942/discussion-between-david-and-rob).

Comment: @Rob, thanks for that, Chrome was caching the OPTIONS preflight request in my case, and disabling the cache solved it

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is that when using Bearer authentication (or any I would imagine), it adds a header "Authorization", and the server will only give an okay if the setup allows for that header.

There's two ways to solve the problem, and below is the *only* code needed. It goes in the `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs` in the Web API solution.

**Method 1:** Allow all headers

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44306")
                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                .AllowAnyHeader());
```

**Method 2:** Allow specific headers

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44306")
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .WithHeaders("authorization", "accept", "content-type", "origin"));
```

The extra headers are because, per the documentation:

> Browsers are not entirely consistent in how they set Access-Control-Request-Headers. If you set headers to anything other than "*", you should include at least "accept", "content-type", and "origin", plus any custom headers that you want to support.

Answer (score 26):

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is returned only if:

1. The request includes an "Origin" header.
2. The requested origin matches the CORS policy.

Then the server returns the ACAO-header with the origin URL as value.

The Origin header is usually set by the XMLHttpRequest object.

For more information, see [How CORS works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#how-cors-works)

Comment: This information helped me. I did set up everything correctly, but forgot to send the `Origin` header when [testing with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I spent hours to get this to work, turns out my configuration was correct but test apps weren't sending an origin

Comment: Thank you, had the same problem as nightblade9!

Comment: And when matching the Origin header, that includes the `https://` prefix... Duh!

Answer (score 4):

In Startup.cs file, add following

```
public CorsPolicy GenerateCorsPolicy(){
                var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
                corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
                corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
                corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin(); // For anyone access.
                //corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:56573"); // for a specific url. Don't add a forward slash on the end!
                corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();
                return corsBuilder.Build();
    }
```

In ConfigureServices method:

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", GenerateCorsPolicy());
                });
```

// To Apply CORS globally throughout the application
  // In Configure method, add

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

[DisableCors]
Using DisableCors attribute, we can disable CORS for a controller or an action.

//To Enable CORS controller basis - If you apply globally you don't need this one.

```
[EnableCors("AllowAllOrigins")]  
public class HomeController: Controller {}
```

Comment: Is it worth adding here that adding all origins would be unsafe (effectively disabling Cors) and it would be better just to specify the origins you want to allow to avoid cross-site scripting being possible?

Answer (score 4):

As of date 03/17/2019, .NET Core version 2.1:

This will possibly save some time to other poor souls...at some point I started to be frustrated and almost gave up on .NET Core WebApi as a separate project.

In real life circumstances, there are other configurations in Startup functions e.g. I had Swagger, DI registrations etc. I wasn't able to make bloody thing work until I put both AddCors() and UseCors() methods to be the first one getting called in configuration functions.

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("SomePolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });



 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors("SomePolicy");
```

After that, calls from Angular 6 app (Swagger Typescript client calls) started to work as a charm.

Comment: @David If in your Setup.cs you only have CORS setup, then there is no difference. 

However, it is more likely that you will have middleware(s) for errors, Facebook, Swagger... In that case, CORS enabling function have to be the first one in pipeline/called in configure functions. Otherwise, it might not work.
Note that UseMvc() have to go after it also, but it is mentioned in lot of articles I saw.

My point was; one have to be careful where and in what context is using these lines of code.

Comment: I've been wrestling with this for hours now. I've seen this method detailed everywhere, but I never get the CORS headers no matter what I do. I just want those headers attached to EVERY response, but judging by what people are saying, it's a monumentally complex task!

Comment: This was it for me. Files were uploading correctly, but the browser was still complaining.

Swapping lines in correct order in Configure fixed it.

        app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins") |> ignore; 
        app.UseGiraffe routes

Answer (score 4):

I wasted **hours** on this problem today, only to discover it's because .Net Core 3 doesn't support preflight OPTIONS requests if you use the Endpoint routing RequirePolicy method of enabling CORS!

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enable-cors-with-endpoint-routing) *does* mention this, but it wasn't called out in an obvious warning block so I'd totally missed it.

The following will fix the problem, but it'll apply a global CORS policy, so caveat emptor!

**Service Configuration:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string[] corsOrigins = Configuration.GetSection("AllowedHosts").Get<string[]>();

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowConfiguredOrigins", builder => builder
            .WithOrigins(corsOrigins)
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
    });
...
```

Basically, **don't** do this:

```
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors();    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("AllowConfiguredOrigins");
    });
...
```

...do **this** instead

Configure()

```
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors("AllowConfiguredOrigins");
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
...
```

Comment: I'm not doing exactly what you said not to do, but is what I'm doing as bad?
`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
             {
                 endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();
             });`

Answer (score 4):

In `Startup.cs` at the end of `ConfigureServices()` add this:

```
services.AddCors();
```

Then in `Configure()` **at the top** add this:

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("*"));

// alternatively you could use .With... methods to specify your restrictions:
// app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins("http://domain1.com").WithMethods("GET","POST").WithHeaders("Authorization").WithExposedHeaders("*"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to add one more possibility for those who may have followed the advice above and it is still not working. In my case I was not getting the header returned (or only getting it on the first request) because of the order of registration in the pipeline.

I changed the order from this:

```
app.UseResponseCaching();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("WideOpen");
app.UseMvc();
```

To this:

```
app.UseCors("WideOpen");
app.UseResponseCaching();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMvc();
```

That resolved my issue.