# Request (using authorization in header) to asp.net core API from Angular 4 not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, bearer-token

I am struggling to make requests using a bearer token from Angular (4) to my Asp Net core API.

Here is how I am doing it from angular:

[image]

My API Startup.cs code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();
  services.AddAuthentication();

  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .WithHeaders("authorization", "accept", "content-type", "origin"));
  });

  // Add the configuration singleton here
  services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
  app.UseOptions();
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
       !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
       !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
    {
      context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
      await next();
    }
  });
  app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
  {
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    {
      context.Response.StatusCode = 500; // or another Status accordingly to Exception Type
      context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

      var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
      if (error != null)
      {
        var ex = error.Error;

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(ex.Message, Encoding.UTF8);
      }
    });
  });

  var jwtAuth = new JwtBearerOptions
  {
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    Authority = $"{Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"]}{Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"]}",
    Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
    TokenValidationParameters =
            new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
              ValidIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Issuer"]
            }
  };
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtAuth);


  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

But I keep getting the Unauthorized error!

[image]
[image]

I have tried many solutions that I've read online, mostly here on stackoverflow ([.NET Core UseCors() does not add headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843973/net-core-usecors-does-not-add-headers), [Enable OPTIONS header for CORS on .NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199757/enable-options-header-for-cors-on-net-core-web-api) and [How to disable OPTIONS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request)), but couldn't get it to wort! :(
When I make the request **using postman, it does work**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Ok .. what a terrible mistake.. I can't believe that I spent so much hours trying to figure this out! 
The problem was between the computer screen and the chair.. I was adding the headers with the Authorization in the wrong angular service!!!