# Will CORS policy prevent resource access from non-browser requests?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

From my understanding, using the CORS module will remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from the resource, causing XmlHttp requests to fail from the browser.

However, does this prevent Http requests from a CURL, or other native applications/web-servers (ie. a request written and run via PHP) from successfully retrieving data from that resource?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> However, does this prevent Http requests from a CURL, or other native applications/web-servers (ie. a request written and run via PHP) from successfully retrieving data from that resource?

No, CORS config won’t prevent non-browser stuff from successfully retrieving your resources.

The same-origin policy is enforced only by browsers. It’s not enforced by servers. (And CORS is a way to relax the same-origin policy.) It’s not the case that if there’s some lack of any CORS details in a request, servers somehow block requests, or refuse to send responses.

Instead when you configure CORS support on a server, all that the server does differently is just to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and other CORS response headers.

The way the protocol works is, regardless of what CORS configuration you make on the server side, all clients—even browsers—continue to get responses from the server as they normally would. But the difference is, `curl` or other native apps or backend server-side programming environments such as PHP will not prevent your client code from accessing the response if it doesn’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. But browsers will.

Specifically, even if you see an error in your browser devtools that a cross-origin request from your frontend JavaScript code failed, you’ll still be able to see the response in devtools.

But just because your browser can see the response doesn’t mean the browser will expose it to your frontend JavaScript code. Browsers only expose responses from cross-origin requests to frontend code running at a particular origin if the server the request went to opts-in to allowing the request, by responding with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header allowing that origin.

But browsers are the only clients which do that. Browsers are the only clients that implement the same-origin policy and the CORS protocol. `curl` or other native applications or HTTP client requests made server-side runtimes such as PHP don’t implement the CORS protocol, so you can’t block requests from them by doing any CORS configuration on the server side.

So If you want to block requests to a resource from non-browser clients, you need to do it using something other than CORS configuration.

Comment: What is the equivalent to cors for server-to-server calls, if there is any? Maybe not an exact equivalent, e.g. I don't want the caller api to have the data if it does not match the criteria. I know about auth methods, I'm wondering if there are alternatives

Comment: There’s no equivalent to CORS for server-to-server calls. The same-origin policy and CORS are fundamentally just about frontend JavaScript code that runs in a browser—running on the client side from individual users’ computers, on behalf of those users. Server-side code doesn’t run that way at all, so the server side has no need for anything like same-origin policy restrictions, and so nothing like CORS is necessary for easing those restrictions. Auth methods really are the only thing that’s remotely related in server-side runtimes—explicit authentication or based on IP address or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

I could successfully prevent a server like Postman to send me a request in my CORS-protected API route by throwing an error if the domain is not in my whitelist and by setting the origin of request dynamically.

Here is my postman in which I set all headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:`

[image]

The request was blocked from Postman server and returning a `500 internal Server Error` after the error is thrown in my live server as you can see here:

[image]

Using Express/Node.js with `cors` version 2.8.5, my code looks like this:

```
const whitelistDomains = [
    'http://awesomesite123.com',
    'https://localhost:3000',
];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelistDomains.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // For legacy browser support
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 1):

Curl and other non browser http clients have to ignore the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. See 
[How can you debug a CORS request with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl)

Answer (score -1):

Ajax is not cross-domain,which is not allowed by any major browser for security reasons. Unless your interface server and your website have the same domain

Comment: This is non-applicable as this is not done through a browser, and the CORS policy isn't enforced/adhered to.