# How to disable CORS completely in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

We need to disable CORS in WebAPI project and I have commented out below line in `Startup.cs` class and `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method.

```
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

By going through [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl), following request is sent

```
curl -H "Origin: http://www.google.com" --verbose \ http://localhost:23422/api/values
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1/1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: XXXX
X-SourceFiles: XXX
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
[
 "value1",
 "value2"
]
```

**It does work and gives back the actual result. Does it mean that the CORS is still supported? I assumed it to not to return any values since I am requesting it from google.com.**

However, when I try the below request. It returns back `405 Method Not Allowed`

```
curl  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: http://google.com" --head \ http://localhost:44312/api/values
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1/1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET,POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: XXXX
X-SourceFiles: XXX
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
{
  "message": "The requested resource does not support http method "OPTIONS"."
}
```

Comment: When you run this command do you get allow cross origin header in the response? if not then CORS isn't allowed.

Comment: I have added the responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not getting allow cross origin header in the response (when your request has the header), this does not prove that cross origin is still enabled.

Assuming cross origin is disabled why do you still get data? Because CORS error happen in an internet browser. It is the browser that block the access. A script written in C#, Powershell, etc, would still have access to resources in any public domain since it's running on a PC, not in an Internet browser.

Answer (score 15):

**This works for me in ASP Net Core:**

I had similar problem.

**In startup.cs - ConfigureServices:**

```
services.AddCors();
```

**In startup.cs - Configure:**

```
 // global cors policy
                app.UseCors(x => x
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                    //.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44351")); // Allow only this origin can also have multiple origins separated with comma
                    .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials
```

**Install NuGet Package:** Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Now its possible to call the api from the browser using ex. Javascript.

**Found here:**
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/20/aspnet-core-api-allow-cors-requests-from-any-origin-and-with-credentials

**Example - accessing from JS fetch api:**

In the JS APP: - fetch api:

```
mode: 'cors', 
credentials: 'include'
```

**EDIT:**
I have tried to understand CORS and this is how I understand it now - Please correct me if I am wrong:

The images are only for reference - the addresses are not the same as in the text.

**CORS:**

**1.** Client makes request to get the webpage from - `https://localhost:5050`

**2.** Client gets the webpage

**3.** Client tries to fetch **“GET”** data from `https://localhost:5050` by using **POST** or **GET** and all is fine.

**4.** We have an API at `https://localhost:6060` and we want to use it together with the  webpage from - `https://localhost:5050`

**5.** Client tries to fetch **“GET”** data from the **API** - `https://localhost:6060`

**6.** Client Gets **CORS Error Message** - Because as Default only the Origin “the address” `https://localhost:6060` is the only one that is allowed to **fetch**, **get**, **post** etc. Like **swagger** etc. that is on the same address can get the data but other **addresses** cant. But how is it possible that other **APIs** can use this **API** without **CORS** configuration on the server. This is because **CORS** is related to the **browsers** and its the browser that stops the response, so using it with other **APIs** without **CORS** is no problem.

**7.** To allow webpages to access the API, its the **Server** that needs to be **configured** for this.

**8.** The server needs to add a **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** `https:/address:port`  header and return the allowed Origin “Address” which is the one that is sending the request.

[image: img1]

**9.** **ASP net Core** is **configured** in the `startup.cs` in the Configure method:

`In ASP net Core is configured in the startup.cs in the Configure method:`

```
     // CORS - Allow calling the API from WebBrowsers
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            //.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44351")); // Allow only this origin can also have multiple origins seperated with comma
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true));// Allow any origin
```

**10.** This means when the server returns an response it will add **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** with the address of the allowed origin.

**11.** Than the browser will get the **response** and will look for **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:**
If this **header** is there and the value is as the **origin** of the **address** that sent the request **“the webpage address”**. Then the response is **allowed** by the **browser**.

**12.** If there is no **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** header that means that the server is not **CORS** configured and should be configured before consuming API data from **browsers** other **APIs** can **GET** and **POST** data but clients through **browsers** can't.

[image: imgerror]

**13.** If there is **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** header with the response but the value is not as the current address, **“the web page address”** then this means that the server is not configured for this particular website.

[image: address]

**Conclussion:**
So the server needs to be configured in order for the website to use the **API**. This is default browser behavior and will look for **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** header if it's not present the browser will refuse to show the response to the client. If the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: is present but the origin value is not the same as the website address the browser will refuse showing the response to the client. This means that in any case the server should be configured with **CORS** **configuration** in order for Clients to access the API  through web browsers. Other APIs etc. can get data from the API because they are not web browsers and there is no web **browser** **blocking** the **response**.

**Misconfiguratin of CORS:**
Like **@ TwoFingerRightClick** said, its not good to have Allow All Origins together with Allow Credentials.

Why allow credentials with allow all origins is not so good. In the post they talk about how user data can be stolen if **CORS** is **misconfigured** like I have done in the code above. I use Credentials and Allow all origins which is **misconfiguratin** of **CORS**. So **allow all origins** should be used without Allow credentials. If **Allow credentials** is needed we need to specify the Origins which we **allow credentials** from. So we need to use the commented line `//.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44351")); // Allow only this origin can also have multiple origins separated with comma`

**Allow Credentials** - Allows Cookies with request and response.

**The Post:** https://we45.com/blog/3-ways-to-exploit-cors-misconfiguration

Comment: Using `.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)` versus `.AllowAnyOrgin()`* permits using `AllowCredentials()` so that you don't have to worry about this rule: "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'." Now you get the least secure site possible (don't be like Steam and release this to Prod and then user's sessions get stolen)! 
*`.AllowAnyOrgin()` can't be used in conjuction with `AllowCredentials()`

Comment: Brilliant answer! I've been messing about with this cors crap for ages and following your post has allowed it to work for me.