# How to Test CORS header

Tags: header, cors, cross-domain

Our application supports CORS configurations headers. 
I have configured testApp separately on two different hosts. Both the setups work independent of each other. 
Application on host1 is configured with CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to pointing to application on host2. 
When I access the application pages of host2 am expecting it to show Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in response. But which is missing.

How to test to CORS headers to confirm its working properly or coded properly to support cross domain resource sharing.

Comment: What about using cUrl? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179364

Answer (score 34):

You can leverage the `fetch` provided by the browser debugger (F12 on Chrome and Firefox, then go to console):

`fetch('https://google.ca')`

If you get a CORS error then that means the current site you opened your debugger with (Origin) is not included in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header by the site you're fetching from.

Answer (score 32):

You could test it with cUrl from terminal.

```
curl -v --request OPTIONS 'https://your-host.here' -H 'Origin: http://some.origin.here' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET'
```

Answer (score 13):

If your application returns the header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin then it should work. In my particular use case I set it to "*".

Otherwise testing will show an error, viewable from a browser console. It will say something like: *Access to ... has been blocked by CORS policy*

[image: CORS not enabled error message from browser console - screen grab]

You can test if the CORS headers are working properly using your browser. 
I used this one and hope this helps. You will find the instructions in it. https://github.com/cactuz/cors-tester-from-browser

Comment: There are extremely few use cases in which you want to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. This will essentially disable authentication for your application, as any website can now hijack your users' sessions.

Comment: @ATOMP albeit the * value is not recommend, ACAO header has nothing to do with authentication and no modern website is using this header as an authentication method.

Comment: @OferB I think you might have missed the point. If you set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * it becomes trivial to use XSS to hijack user sessions, thus essentially disabling authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix to test API's locally.

**1 - Clone the CORS anywhere proxy server**
From terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere.git
```

**2 - Navigate to the directory where you cloned it**
From terminal:

```
cd [Project folder]
```

**3 - Install Node**
From terminal:

```
npm install
```

**4 - Start proxy server**
From terminal:

```
npm start
```

**5 - Navigate to the folder that contains your API project. Create a variable like so**
proxyUrl="http://localhost:8080/"

**6 - Make sure that this variable is in front of any API calls base URL.
Example:**

```
async function apiCall() {
    proxyUrl="http://localhost:8080/";
    baseUrl="api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901";
    endPoint=proxyURL + baseUrl;
    let response = await(endPoint, {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        cache: "no-cache",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        redirect: "follow",
        referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
        });
    let jsonResponse = await response.json();
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

You can test it with any rest client like **POSTMAN Rest Client**, or simply you can check it from **browser console - > Network tab -> in xhr filter** - check the header for the particular request. you can check request and response.

Comment: No, you can't test CORS with Postman. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36486188/1811043

Comment: Why can't you? Can't you look at the header of the response to see? You can look for "access-control-allow-origin".

Comment: Postman is always 'same origin', so it is not a real test

Comment: If the "Origin" header is set in the request, the server will send CORS headers back even to postman client.

Comment: Also send "Access-Control-Request-Method" in the request header