# Why Can't I Fetch a Webpage (With NodeJS and Node-Fetch)?

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I am trying to fetch a site: [link here](https://matchmaker.krunker.io/seek-game?hostname=krunker.io&region=us-ca-sv&game=SV%3A4jve9&autoChangeGame=false&validationToken=QR6beUGVKUKkzwIsKhbKXyaJaZtKmPN8Rwgykea5l5FkES04b6h1RHuBkaUMFnu%2B&dataQuery=%7B%7D). If you click on the link, it shows JSON: `{"error":"Socket Error"}`. I am trying to fetch that website, and return the error.

However, I get a `403 Forbidden` error instead. Is there a reason for this? I turned CORS off, but I don't think it did anything. Here is an example of what I have tried:

```js
async function b(){
  error = await fetch('https://matchmaker.krunker.io/seek-game?hostname=krunker.io&region=us-ca-sv&game=SV%3A4jve9&autoChangeGame=false&validationToken=QR6beUGVKUKkzwIsKhbKXyaJaZtKmPN8Rwgykea5l5FkES04b6h1RHuBkaUMFnu%2B&dataQuery=%7B%7D', {mode:'no-cors'}).then(res=>res.json())
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
}
b()
```

Why doesn't anything seem to work?
Please comment if there is anything I need to add, this is my first Stack Overflow post so I am still slightly confused by what makes a good question. Thanks for helping!!

NOTE: My environment is Node.JS (testing on Repl.it which I think uses the latest Node version).

Comment: Are you controlling the server side here? Maybe they only allow requests from certain servers

Comment: @LucaKiebel, No I do not control the server side. However, I do know that CORS mode Access-Control-Allow-Origin is blocking me (at least I think).

Comment: Then you can't really do anything against it. If they dont offer a public API, and they dont want you to access theirs, it wont work

Comment: @LucaKiebel ok, thanks for helping!

Comment: You might want to play with your (fetch) request headers to mimic your browser. Or simply to mimic curl headers (or use curl), which seems to work fine :-)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Thanks for commenting! I thought of doing this, but couldn't seem to change my user-agent (which seems to be the problem). If you know of any way to do this, please write an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @imaginate, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular host is protected width [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com) anti DDoS protection. The server doesn't accept requests made by `fetch`, but the do accept requests from `curl`. God knows why.

```sh
$ curl 'https://matchmaker.krunker.io/seek-game?hostname=krunker.io&region=us-ca-sv&game=SV%3A4jve9&autoChangeGame=false&validationToken=QR6beUGVKUKkzwIsKhbKXyaJaZtKmPN8Rwgykea5l5FkES04b6h1RHuBkaUMFnu%2B&dataQuery=%7B%7D'

// => {"error":"Socket Error"}
```

You can use `curl` in node.js with [node-libcurl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl) package.

```js
const { curly } = require('node-libcurl')
const url = 'https://matchmaker.krunker.io/seek-game?hostname=krunker.io&region=us-ca-sv&game=SV%3A4jve9&autoChangeGame=false&validationToken=QR6beUGVKUKkzwIsKhbKXyaJaZtKmPN8Rwgykea5l5FkES04b6h1RHuBkaUMFnu%2B&dataQuery=%7B%7D'

curly.get(url)
    .then(({ statusCode, data }) => console.log(statusCode, data))

// => 400 { error: 'Socket Error' }
```

Works as expected :-)

Comment: Thanks so much! This solution worked for a couple of days, now it seems like I am getting blocked again. I will keep this as the answer, but could you possibly try to update it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Might be that Cloudflare anti DDoS protection identified you as a bot and blocked your access.

Comment: See if that URL still works from a browser on the same IP.

Comment: It has to do with the origin. I went to `https://matchmaker.krunker.io` and ran the function `b()` (shown above) and I got the resulting `{ error: 'Socket Error' }`. I know that you can set the origin in cURL using a `-H` header (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl)) but don't know how to do this using `node-libcurl`. Thanks :)

Comment: You can respond to my [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054601/can-you-set-an-origin-header-using-node-libcurl) if you want. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy such as allorigins.win which is a cors proxy that can retrieve the data from a URL in the form of json. You can fetch from this URL: https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://matchmaker.krunker.io/game-list?hostname=krunker.io

Comment: Your answer must contain an example in code ...
After all, this question is old ...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.