# Can You Set An Origin Header Using node-libcurl?

Tags: node.js, get, node-libcurl

I know that you can set the origin in cURL using a -H header like this:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://foo.bar.com" --verbose \
  https://example.com
```

is there a `node-libcurl` way of setting -H headers? This is my current get request:

```js
const { curly } = require('node-libcurl')
async function test(){
  mm = await curly.get('https://example.com')
  console.log(mm)
}
test()
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom headers for GET request are not documented. But judging from [POST request examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl#simple-request---async--await-using-curly), I'd try something like this:

```js
const { curly } = require('node-libcurl')

curly.get('https://example.com', {
    httpHeader: [
        'Origin: http://foo.bar.com',
        ...
    ]
}).then(console.log)
```

Comment: sadly, I still get the error. Thanks so much for trying, though!

Comment: I'm afraid mimicking a real user behaviour would take more than just an Origin Header...