# Spring CORS Header not being sent

Tags: java, spring, cors

I am trying to set up CORS for my Spring REST API.
I have the following Configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

However, whenever I test my endpoint with swagger, there is no CORS Header.

I also tried setting CORS at the Endpoints directly:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/news/articles")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*") 
@RestController
public class NewsEndpoint {
```

But the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

[Since Spring 5.3.2, `allowedOriginPatterns` is supported to specify the patterns instead of literal values](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26111#issuecomment-729805112). The `allowedOrigins`, if has `*` as value, won't be added in the header if `allowCredentials=true`, which I think is the default setting.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*") // <= this line
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response, now I got a "vary" header. Is that what I want?

Comment: `vary: Origin` ensures that no cached value can be used when the browser/client fills the Origin header in the request. [This is very important from Security POV](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/268962/164617). Do verify the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` [header in the response using Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47609921/6519224).

Comment: @DeepakD Not exactly. Rather, `Vary: Origin` signals to caching intermediaries that the `Origin` header should be part of their cache key.