# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy in Django

Tags: reactjs, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I have deployed a web app and created a sub domain for it as the url of its backend (e.g main url is domain.com and subdomain is api.domain.com) and both are in https, too.

While I request from frontend to my created api in Django Rest Framework I get the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource

Code below is the part of my settings.py.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I shall be thankful for giving me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

On the [django-cors-headers documentation](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#setup) :

> CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but still the problem and error persists. Do you have other solution?

Comment: So your configuration of django-cors-headers seems to be ok. The problem may be caused by something else. Are you sure your requests are hitting your django app ? Do you have any django log to check that ?

Comment: Yeah I think so, because while the I run my backend and frontend in local, everything is fine and I am also sure about the DRF api too. Can you guide me more please that what I can I do now according to your statement?

Comment: If I were you, I could use curl to test my API in order to find out the problem like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl

Comment: then I could know were is the problem : on the configuration of django-cors-header, on the webserver part, on the frontend part...

Comment: Hi again, the problem is solved and that was with the ./htaccess of my backend subdomain.
Now, I have a question and will thank you for you answer.
I have a main domain which is for my Vue.js that is domain.com and I also have a sub-domain for my DRF backend with the name of api.domain.com; I do not want that the api and urls in my backend to be accessible under the corresponded url; e.g if anyone enters the url of api.domain.com/companies my backend info and data are being shown there but I want to remove access for anyone to see all of the pages of the backend subdomain. How can I do that?

Comment: Following the StackOverflow rules, you should create a new question for each of your problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372104/restrict-access-to-drf-subdomain-on-host    ; This is the link of my question, can you answer me there please?