# Restrict Access to DRF subdomain on host

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, web-hosting

I have a main domain which is for my Vue.js that is domain.com and I also have a sub-domain for my DRF backend with the name of api.domain.com; I do not want that the api and urls in my backend to be accessible under the corresponded url; e.g if anyone enters the url of api.domain.com/companies my backend info and data are being shown there but I want to remove access for anyone to see all of the pages of the backend subdomain. How can I do that?

Comment: Add authentication for your backend.

Comment: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy/24723/9